# Can´t slide through content inside sections, its better use other plugin?

Tags: jquery, jcarousel, jcarousellite

I Want to show the first two sections in my home page, and then when the user clicks on "SHOW MORE NEWS", the first two news disappear and the other two that I have hidden appear.
Its possible to make sections slide with jCarousel?
Because  I've tried many ways and never work.
Its better use other plugin for slide through content sections?

Import jQuery libs

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jcarousellite_1.0.1.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js?ver=1.9.1'></script>
```

HTML:

```
         <div id="news-content">

             <h1>News</h1>
             <hr/>

             <div id="firstnews">

             <article id="loop-news">
               <img src="image1.png" />
               <a href="#">Title 1</a>
               <p>Text Title 1</h3>
           </article>


             <article id="loop-news">
               <img src="image2.png" />
               <a href="#">Title 2</a>
               <p>Text Title 2</p>
               <h3>Read more</h3>
           </article>

          </div>

          <!-- Just want to show this articles below when click on "SHOW MORE NEWS" -->

          <div id="secondnews">

             <article id="loop-news">
               <img src="image1.png" />
               <a href="#">Text only show</a>
               <p>Text Title 1</h3>
           </article>


             <article id="loop-news">
               <img src="image2.png" />
               <a href="#">Title 2</a>
               <p>Text Title 2</p>
               <h3>Read more</h3>
             </article>

           </div>

           <hr/>
           <a href="#" id="nextBtn">SHOW MORE NEWS(+)</a>

           </div>
```

Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("news-content").jCarouselLite({
              btnPrev: "#nextBTN",
              visible: 1
            })
        });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, I think jcarousel works better only with images.
Probably Bj content slider is what you need http://www.byjoomla.com/joomla-extensions/content-slider